# How can I find my application's resource group/map in XCode?

Tags: xcode

How can I find my application's resource group/map in XCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually resources are grouped in a 'Resources' group (yellow folder icon) in the Project navigator (left sidebar).

You may also want to look at the Copy Bundle Resources list of the Build Phases tab of your target settings. That list displays everything that is being copied into the bundle along with the executable.

Comment: but i need the Resources groupe

Comment: I cant find the Resources group